# Where does the variable slug comes from in gatsby graphql query?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

We create the slug node in `gatsby-node.js`. Then we create the createPage

```
  const posts = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
  posts.forEach(({ node: post }) => {
    createPage({
      path: `posts${post.fields.slug}`,
      component: PostTemplate,
      context: {
        slug: post.fields.slug,
        testingSomething: "this is a test",
      },
    })
  })
```

In the template we run something like this.

```
const PostTemplate = ({ data: post }) => {
  return ( ...)  }

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      ...
  }
`
export default PostTemplate
```

How does `graphql` know that there's a slug? If it did something like `this.props.pageContext.slug` fine, but what's going on under the hud?

How does the variable `$slug` get populated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To add variables to page component queries, pass these in the context object when creating pages.

[Query variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#query-variables)

```
const posts = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
posts.forEach(({ node: post }) => {
  createPage({
    path: `posts${post.fields.slug}`,
    component: PostTemplate,
    context: {
      slug: post.fields.slug,
      testingSomething: "this is a test",
    },
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I got that part, I was wondering how then `query($slug: String!) ...` understands that it should look inside context without anything like `this.context.slug`

Comment: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/49fd769f695ccfa6e990e3eaae7c886f073db19b/packages/gatsby/src/redux/actions/public.js#L155